# Template pattern - not useful for small projects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm sorry to ask such a localized question but until I get confirmation I don't feel confident moving on with my project.

I have read lots about the template pattern, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) has a good example.

It shows that you create the basic virtual methods and then inherit the base class and override where you want. The example on the site is for Monopoly and Chess which both inherit the base class.

So, my question is, if you had an application which was only going to be Chess and never anything else, would there be any benefit in using the template pattern (other than as an education exercise)?

Comment: The wikipedia example is rather absurd. The difference between Chess and Monopoly isn't four tiny methods -- there is an entire infrastructure that is needed for one and not the other.

Comment: Check this article, could give you a better understanding of real scenarios usage http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307452/6-common-use-of-Template-Design-pattern-Design-pat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, I think that falls under the category of "[You Ain't Gonna Need It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it)."

To be more specific, design patterns exist to solve a particular problem, and if your code doesn't need to solve that problem, all they do is add lines of code without having any benefit.

Comment: I had guessed this would be the case. It's just good to hear the confirmation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No. Expressed in a very simplified and superficial way, the template pattern is just worthwhile starting at a certain relationship between total code size and templated code size. In your example, the chess game is going to be the entire program, so there'll be no need to use the template pattern here.

Answer (score 2):

The template pattern is used in specific situations. It is used when you want to sketch out an algorithm but let the specific steps differ.

This *could* be useful in a Chess application. However, you should not start developing an application with the idea 'I'm going to use this pattern and that one and..'. Instead, you develop the code and you discover that you need certain patterns.

This is where a Test Driven Development approach is really handy. It allows you to refactor your code each step of the way.

A nice book that explains this is [Refactoring To Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will check out the book.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing your chess game and then if in the future coming back and changing things to fit monopoly too. But its something totally different if you want to use the pattern  to learn the pattern, in that case its good to start simple so the complex is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the parts of the program. The whole idea of Template is to have an algorithm that never changes and to be able to add or edit certain steps of that algorithm.

It may well be that you never change, however, this is the issue with design principles, it IS good practice and you may later wish you'd implemented them. I would say though that if you are 100% sure then you can leave it out as it usually saves time and lines of code. Depends if you want to learn Template usage or not.

Also the [GOF principles website](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx) is quite good:

Comment: Let's just assume then, that my second game can't end. My base class has 2 virtual methods which are displayWinner() and endGame(). This would mean I'm inheriting a base class where I'm only using a small % of what is available - is that a bad thing?

Comment: Yes. Inheritance should adhere to the Liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).